# htmlunit 2.11 doesn't work with https

Tags: https, htmlunit

We are using HtmlUnit Version 2.11 i.e. the latest version

If we pass a url with https protocol to webClient.getPage it thows  the following exception and fails to work

```
@Test
public void TC001_VerifyHomePageLaunch() throws Exception {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_10);
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://localhost/abc/test.jsp");

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
```

javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Please help us with the steps on how to get rid of this error and go ahead with actual testing.
We don't have certificates installed as this is a test machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following setting with your WebClient:

```
webClient.setUseInsecureSSL(true)
```

Documenation states:

> If set to true, the client will accept connections to any host, regardless of whether they have valid certificates or not. This is especially useful when you are trying to connect to a server with expired or corrupt certificates.

[Link to source](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClientOptions.html#setUseInsecureSSL%28boolean%29).